# Kotlin: Override setter

Tags: kotlin, setter

I have an abstract class containing the following property

```
var items: List<I> = listOf()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        onDataChanged()
    }
```

In my extending class i now want to override the setter of `items` to do additional stuff before the above setter code is called. Is this possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to declare your field as `open` in your parent class

```
open var items: List<I> = listOf()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        onDataChanged()
    }
```

And in your child class you override it as:

```
override var items: List<Int>
    get() = super.items
    set(value) {
        super.items = value
        //Your code
    }
```

In this way, you are actually creating a property without a backing field and you are just accessing to the real parent's `items` field.

---